# How to create an extension of Collection that removes null values?

Tags: ios, swift, collections, null

I have this code, but it shows error:

```
extension Collection {

    func removingOptionals() -> [Element] {
        var result = [Element](); // Error: cannot call value of non-function type '[Self.Element.Type]'
        self.forEach({ (element) in if let el = element { result.append(el); } });
        return result;
    }

}
```

If I removed the `()`, the error becomes: `Expected member name or constructor call after type name`.

This code is supposed to transform `[String?]` into `[String]` by discarding all the null values. Or any other optional data types.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flatMap {}` for this, instead of creation own function. Here is example of usage:

```
let strings: [String?] = ["One", nil, "Two"]
print(strings.flatMap { $0 })
```

And result will be `["One", "Two"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to use the flatMap behavior of the Optional as the other answer shows, but it's going to be [deprecated on the next Swift iteration](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md).

If you want to add the extension to the collection type, you need to be a create a type to box the Optional (You can't extend Collection if the type is generic, like Optional).

```
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    func map<U>(_ f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {}

extension Collection where Iterator.Element: OptionalType {
    func removeNils() -> [Iterator.Element.Wrapped] {

        var result: [Iterator.Element.Wrapped] = []
        result.reserveCapacity(Int(self.count))

        for element in self {
            if let element = element.map({ $0 }) {
                result.append(element)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```